# Page renders using router.use but gives a 'Cannot GET. error with router.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to javascript and node.js I am learning online and trying to create a cms using node.js, express and sqlite. Before going to details I will give you guys my directory structure.

- rootdir

  - node_modules
  - public

    - css (generic styling files)
    - vendor (bootstrap and js files)
  - routes

    - defaultRoutes.js
  - views

    - default

      - index.handlebars
    - partials

      - default

        - (header and footer files)
    - layouts

      - main.handlebars
  - app.js
  - package-lock.json
  - package.json

app.js is where the server is created and defaultRoutes are for routes. When I run

```
    //code in defaultRoutes.js
     const express = require('express');
     const router = express.Router();

     router.use((req,res) => {
     res.render('default/index');
     });

     module.exports = router;
```

and

```
    //code in app.js
    //Routes
     const defaultRoutes = require('./routes/defaultRoutes');
     app.use(defaultRoutes);
```

the page renders but when I change the router.use in defaultRoutes to router.get the browser throws cannot GET error.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: router.get expects first parameter a url string, so you cant just change this to .get. you can do ``router.get('/', (req,res) => {
     res.render('default/index');
     });`` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a route when using `router.get()`. `router.use()` can work for any route, but to define a route with `router.get()` you can add the route like this:

```
//code in defaultRoutes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
res.render('default/index');
});

module.exports = router;
```